# How to add dotted lines in the android acharteninge line graph?

Tags: android, graph, achartengine, android-graphview, dotted-line

I have try to add dotted lines in the acharteninge graph body. But i didn't succeed. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
 XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    multiRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    multiRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
    multiRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.rgb(0,0,0));
    multiRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    multiRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(22.2f);
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(22.2f);
    multiRenderer.setChartTitle("");
    multiRenderer.setXTitle("\n Weak Graph");
    multiRenderer.setYTitle("Result in"+"Units");
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true); 
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
    multiRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    multiRenderer.setYAxisMin(2);
    multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {30, 80, 10, 10});
```

I want dotted lines like this image.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2NGqFM-F0bNZDVCbkRkRUkxdTg/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

But i got graph is like this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2NGqFM-F0bNVGdhTkFkZ3AzejQ/edit?usp=sharing
 [image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method

```
multiRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
```